# Is the article “a” required in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, articles

Sailing is **a** serious job. 
Sailing is serious job.

I found that job is a countable noun, so it look like "a serious job" is the right answer, but the other phrase doesn't sound wrong either.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The indefinite article "a" is required!

Correct: "Sailing is a serious job."

Sorry, but I don't have the exact grammatical explanation off the top of my head. But as a native speaker, that's the right answer.

Comment: You could say "Sailing is serious work" but, as you say, 'job' is a countable noun so it needs an article.